# Close activity if Idle

Tags: android, android-activity, timeout

I have an application and I need the `Activity` to close automatically if it is idle, that is, if the user does not touch the screen for 30 seconds, `Activity` closes automatically. While the user is using (touching) the `Activity`, it will remain open.

I'm using the `CountDownTimer` method, but even though the user is using the app, it closes.

Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `touch listener` like this and reset your countdown timer or the thread you use for closing the activity

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    //mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

int action = event.getActionMasked();

switch (action) {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        initialX = event.getX();
        initialY = event.getY();

        Log.d(TAG, "Action was DOWN");
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        Log.d(TAG, "Action was MOVE");
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        float finalX = event.getX();
        float finalY = event.getY();

        Log.d(TAG, "Action was UP");

        if (initialX < finalX) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Left to Right swipe performed");
        }

        if (initialX > finalX) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Right to Left swipe performed");
        }

        if (initialY < finalY) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Up to Down swipe performed");
        }

        if (initialY > finalY) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Down to Up swipe performed");
        }

        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        Log.d(TAG,"Action was CANCEL");
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
        Log.d(TAG, "Movement occurred outside bounds of current screen element");
        break;
}

return super.onTouchEvent(event);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

How about cancelling and starting the timer.

```
@Override
public void onUserInteraction() {
    super.onUserInteraction();
    yourCountDownTimer.cancel();
    yourCountDownTimer.start();
}
```